# Replacing a Matched Character in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, text

I have a text file of 3 name entries:

```
# dot_test.txt
001 AALTON, Alan .....25 Every Street
006 JOHNS, Jason .... 3 Steep Street
002 BROWN. James .... 101 Browns Road
```

My task is to find instances of NAME. when it should be NAME, using the following:

```
Select-String -AllMatches -Path $input_path -Pattern '(?s)[A-Z]{3}.*?\D(?=\s|$)' -CaseSensitive |
    ForEach-Object { if($_.Matches.Value -match '\.$'){$_.Matches.Value -replace '\,$'} }
```

The output is:

```
BROWN.
```

The conclusion is this script block identifies the instance of NAME. but fails to make the replacement.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `$_.Matches.Value -replace '\,$'`

This attempts to replace a `,` (which you needn't escape as `\,`) at the end of (`$`) your match *with the empty string* (due to the absence of a second, *replacement* operand), i.e. it would effectively *remove* a trailing `,`.

However, given that your match contains no `,` and that you instead want to replace its trailing `.` with `,`, use the following:

```
$_.Matches.Value -replace '\.$', ','  # -> 'BROWN,'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-replace` directly, and if you need to replace both a comma and dot at the end of the string, use `[.,]$` regex:

```
Select-String -AllMatches -Path $input_path -Pattern '(?s)[A-Z]{3}.*?\D(?=\s|$)' -CaseSensitive | % {$_.Matches.Value -replace '\.$', ','}
```

*Details*:

- `(?s)[A-Z]{3}.*?\D(?=\s|$)` - matches

  - `(?s)` - `RegexOptions.Singleline` mode on and `.` can match line breaks
  - `[A-Z]{3}` - three uppercase ASCII letters
  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
  - `\D` - any non-digit char
  - `(?=\s|$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location either immediately followed with a whitespace or end of string.

The `\.$` pattern matches a `.` at the end of string.

Comment: I have a lot of names in the text file. Most of them are correctly formatted eg NAME, (comma) but due to OCR output some have a full stop instead of the comma. I am trying to replace the full stops after the names which are incorrect. Your example removes both of these punctuation symbols from after all names.